# Vuejs test on select dropdown element

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to test a dynamic change that occurs on the page, depending on which option of a select dropdown menu is chosen. Unfortunately everything I tried doesn't seem to trigger the event. Here is my code

```
<select v-model="payment" required class="form-control payment">
   <option>Card</option>
   <option>Paypal</option>
</select>
```

and the test

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(Payment, { localVue })
const select = wrapper.find('.form-control payment')
select.setSelected('Paypal')
select.trigger('change')
```

I also tried setSelectedValue and setValue ainstead of setSelected.

How can I correctly select an option? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Like this

```
wrapper.find({name:'select'}).vm.$emit('onChange', 'Paypal')
await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
expect(wrapper.vm.payment).toBe('Paypal')
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Oh, so the problem was not the select itself, but that it should've been an async function. Thank you!